# Getting file name of encrypted file

Tags: java, file, encryption, javafx, aes

I am encrypting a file in my program and creating an extensionless file on my desktop, it all works perfectly for txt, but some extensions like pdf, rtf are popping error messages. I am trying to get the exact same file name for selected file to be created.

```
 runEncrypt.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                    File inputFile = new File(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    File encryptedFile = new File("/Users/aktasberk/Desktop/E_"+selectedFile.getName());
                    try {
                        String key = "16BitKeyIsHere16";
                        CryptoUtils.encrypt(key, inputFile, encryptedFile);
                        //  CryptoUtils.decrypt(key, encryptedFile, decryptedFile);
                    } catch (CryptoException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

As you can see I put "E_ + selectedFile.getname()" to work, what should I do to get only file name without the "E_" and still create the file on desktop.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the error messages you get?

Comment: @patrick-hainge Not in the compiler but when I try to open that encrypted file from desktop it displays some message like , "Corrupted file unable to open" , then I go to file preferences and remove its extension manually, it works that way.

Comment: Well, when you encrypt a file and keep the file extension the file can't be opened by the associated software. you should remove the extension from the filename before writing the encrypted file

Comment: @Michael alright so that will be done manually just as I did thats in the pocket, how about creating an encrypted file which will get its original file name without its extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files extensions like txt are plain text and only save the text that contains. The pdf files have other data that you don't see in the pdf viewer like metadata for example, so when you try to open a file *.pdf which has been encrypted the format of the internal data change and dont follow the pdf style, so the interpreter can't read ir propetly.

For example if the pdf format requires one filed like "letter size", an when you encrypted the file it transforms into AsG45, the viewer can't read it and detects the file is corrupt

In your case, if you want to decrypt after save on desktop, you can name the file E_extension_fileName. with this you can decrypt the file in the future and know what extension had the original file

Comment: Thanks, I understood. At one point user must do these naming and extension stuff manually as you mentioned for future uses.

Comment: @BerkAktaş you can do it in your code, if you split the selectedFile.getName() by the dot. The second position in the array will be the extension